# Apache reverse proxy not preserving headers

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, http-headers

Does anyone know if there is something strange going on? It seems that my reverse proxy setup, doesn't preserve the correct caching headers from the original virtualhost.

*Let me explain...*

I am currently using PHP Slim to create an API for my web app. It has its own caching mechanisms, which are setup and running fine. So, when visiting the resource `api.example.com/info` for example, I have a **Last-Modified** that is set, which allows it to be cached (it doesn't change very often).

As such, the headers looks something like:

```
Request URL:http://api.example.com/info
Request Method:GET
Status Code:304 Not Modified
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.example.com
If-Modified-Since:Mon, 04 Oct 2010 08:00:52  1100
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5
```

Response Headers

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Tue, 19 Jun 2012 22:34:45 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) PHP/5.3.8
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Which shows that the resource returns with a 304 - it's been retrieved from cache. Great!

However, the web app accesses this from a reverse proxy (cross domain issues). When accessing the exact same resource, this time from `app.example.com/api/info`, it returns with a 200 code. Its also noteably slower to load, which makes me think something isn't working.

This time, the headers are

```
Request URL:http://app.example.com/api/info
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:app.example.com
If-Modified-Since:Mon, 04 Oct 2010 08:00:52 GMT
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5
```

Response Headers

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:1959
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 19 Jun 2012 22:41:01 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Last-Modified:Mon, 04 Oct 2010 08:00:52 GMT
Server:Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) PHP/5.3.8
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-API-Version:v1.0
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.8, Slim
```

Any ideas? Sorry about the mass of header info above - didn't want to leave out any information.

Comment: Which `If-Modified-Since` header is right? One or the other has a borked time zone.

Comment: Well picked up! The `If-Modified-Since:Mon, 04 Oct 2010 08:00:52 +1100` is the correct one (AEST). Would that make a difference?

Comment: I would check to make sure the time (and time zone) is correctly set on the reverse proxy machine.

Comment: It's actually the same physical server, so i'm unsure about how to check that...Besides, they're both the same time, just differing timezone, which has to be fixed, but unfortunately doesn't seem to whats causing the issue...

Comment: @crawf if the content was modified in the 11 hours between +1100 and GMT, then yes one of those would have a stale cache.  The same day an hour in +1100 and +0000 are not the same time.  What are the response headers from api.domain.com the first time (before the client has the resource in its cache)?  I do notice the If-Modified-Since and Last-Modified headers have the same time.  Maybe that is significant?

Comment: Is `mod_expires` active and `ExpiresActive` off?

Answer (score 2):

When i compare your both example request, I see some more differeneces between them.

e.g. the second response (throught the proxy) includes an

```
Content-Encoding:gzip
```

Line. Maybe your reverse proxy adds an gzip compression filter before delivering the results.
What could mean: you primary resource did not change and but the proxy changes the content by compressing it, and so it labels this as "new content".

Another difference is in your request: in your first request you send:

```
If-Modified-Since:Mon, 04 Oct 2010 08:00:52 +1100
```

but in your second request the timeoffset `+1100` is missing, so you`re sending another modification time.